# Efficient spatial joining for large dataset in R

Tags: r, spatial-join

I am working with rather large data frames that I often need to do a spatial join on. The fastest way I have come up with so far is this method:

```
library(rgdal)

download.file("http://gis.ices.dk/shapefiles/ICES_ecoregions.zip",
              destfile = "ICES_ecoregions.zip")
unzip("ICES_ecoregions.zip")

# read eco region shapefiles
ices_eco <- rgdal::readOGR(".", "ICES_ecoregions_20150113_no_land", verbose = FALSE)
## Make a large data.frame (361,722 rows) with positions in the North Sea:
lon <- seq(-18.025, 32.025, by=0.05)
lat <- seq(48.025, 66.025, by=0.05)
c <- expand.grid(lon=lon, lat=lat)

# Get the Ecoregion for each position
pings  <- SpatialPoints(c[c('lon','lat')],proj4string=ices_eco@proj4string)
c$area   <- over(pings,ices_eco)$Ecoregion
```

But this takes a very long time and uses a lot of RAM, and will sometime come up with the Error: cannot allocate vector of size 460 Kb (if you can't reproduce the error, just make c larger).

Anyone can come up with a better/faster/more efficient solution?

Comment: I tried to execute your code but I didn't find any defined data frame or what is the `c` object in `c[c('lon','lat')]` example. Can you check everything in your code is working so we can help you?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that i had moved the "c <-". It is corrected now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, performing a more efficient function could mean speed up the process on how quickly the computer can undertake that action (**algorithmic efficiency**). And...

> **Efficient R programming** is the implementation of efficient programming
>   practices in R. All languages are different, so efficient R code does
>   not look like efficient code in another language. Many packages have
>   been optimised for performance so, for some operations, achieving
>   maximum computational efficiency may simply be a case of selecting the
>   appropriate package and using it correctly. There are many ways to get
>   the same result in R, and some are very slow. Therefore not writing
>   slow code should be prioritized over writing fast code. [(Taken from Efficient R book)](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/introduction.html#what-is-efficiency)

So, performing more efficient **Spatial Joins** for large data sets could imply write faster code. In this case, I assume that the `over` function from `sp` package have been optimized for performance and I won't write another function by myself or look for another `R` package.

Instead of that, I will show how to *go parallel* in `R` and speed up the process by using all the CPUs in your computer. Please try the commented and reproducible code example below:

### Load data

```
# Load libraries
library(rgdal)

# Load data
download.file("http://gis.ices.dk/shapefiles/ICES_ecoregions.zip",
              destfile = "ICES_ecoregions.zip")
unzip("ICES_ecoregions.zip")

# Read ecoregions shapefiles
ices_eco <- rgdal::readOGR(".", "ICES_ecoregions_20150113_no_land",
                           verbose = FALSE)

# Make a large data.frame (361,722 rows) with positions in the North Sea:
lon <- seq(-18.025, 32.025, by = 0.05)
lat <- seq(48.025, 66.025, by = 0.05)
df <- expand.grid(lon = lon, lat = lat)
df$area <- NA # Add empty attribute called "area" to assign ecoregions after

# Create a SpatialPointsDataFrame object from dataframe
coordinates(df) <- c("lon", "lat")

# Add projection to SpatialPointsDataFrame object
proj4string(df) <- ices_eco@proj4string
```

### Aim: get the Ecoregion from *ices_eco* `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object for each position in the *df* `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object

```
# Parallel process: using multiple CPUs cores

# Load 'parallel' package for support Parallel computation in R
library('parallel')

# Calculate the number of cores (let one core be free for your Operative System)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

# Cut df in "n" parts
# Higher "n": less memory requiered but slower
# Lower "n": more memory requiered but faster
n <- 1000
parts <- split(x = 1:length(df), f = cut(1:length(df), n))
```

#### Initiate cluster like this if you are on Mac or Linux OSes

[image: MacOS] [image: LinuxOS]

```
# Initiate Cluster of CPU cores
# Note: you have to define all the used objects in the parallel process
# eg.: ices_eco, df, n, parts, etc. before making the cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, type = "FORK")

print(cl) # summary of the cluster
```

#### Initiate cluster like this if you are on Windows OS

[image: WindowsOS]

```
# Initiate Cluster of CPU cores
# Note: you have to define all the used objects in the parallel process
# eg.: ices_eco, df, n, parts, etc. before making the cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, type = "PSOCK")

# Load libraries on clusters
clusterEvalQ(cl = cl, expr = c(library('sp')))

# All the objects required to run the function
# Objects to export to clusters
clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c("ices_eco", "df", "parts", "n"))

print(cl) # summary of the cluster
```

#### Continue running the parallel function

```
# Parallelize sp::over function
# Returns a list with the overlays
system.time(

  overParts <- parLapply(cl = cl, X = 1:n, fun = function(x) {
    over <- over(df[parts[[x]],], ices_eco)
    gc() # release memory
    return(over)
  })
)

# user  system elapsed
# 1.050   1.150 627.111

# Stop Cluster of CPU cores
stopCluster(cl)

# Merge df with ecoregions
for (i in 1:n) {

  message(paste("Merging part", i, "of", n))
  df$area[parts[[i]]] <- as.character(overParts[[i]]$Ecoregion)

}
```

### Control check

```
# Control check by random sampling of 20 elements
randomSampling <- sample(x = 1:length(df), size = 20)

chkA <- as.character(over(df[randomSampling,], ices_eco, returnList = FALSE)$Ecoregion) # direct method
chkB <- df$area[randomSampling] # sample df

# chkA should be equal to chkB
print(cbind(chkA, chkB))

# chkA                         chkB
# [1,] NA                           NA
# [2,] "Baltic Sea"                 "Baltic Sea"
# [3,] NA                           NA
# [4,] "Baltic Sea"                 "Baltic Sea"
# [5,] "Baltic Sea"                 "Baltic Sea"
# [6,] NA                           NA
# [7,] NA                           NA
# [8,] "Celtic Seas"                "Celtic Seas"
# [9,] NA                           NA
# [10,] NA                           NA
# [11,] "Baltic Sea"                 "Baltic Sea"
# [12,] "Oceanic Northeast Atlantic" "Oceanic Northeast Atlantic"
# [13,] "Greater North Sea"          "Greater North Sea"
# [14,] NA                           NA
# [15,] NA                           NA
# [16,] "Faroes"                     "Faroes"
# [17,] NA                           NA
# [18,] NA                           NA
# [19,] NA                           NA
# [20,] "Baltic Sea"                 "Baltic Sea"
```

**Note:** if you can access more than one computer, you can use a cluster of computers all *going parallel*.

### More information here:

- [how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips](http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/)
- [parallel-computing-in-r](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/01/parallel-computing-in-r/)
- [running-r-jobs-quickly-on-many-machines](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/01/running-r-jobs-quickly-on-many-machines/)
- [Parallelizing and Clustering example in R](https://github.com/guzmanlopez/parallelizingAndClusteringInR)

Comment: This looks promising, but I can not make it work in Windows. I tried reading here: http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/ but its not working for some reason.

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: Well, I am trying to make it work inside a loop, and I have difficulties figuring out where to put the parts <- split(x = 1:length(df), f = cut(1:length(df), n)) . If it is inside i get the error message "Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'parts' not found", and I cannot put it outside, since I run it on several df's.

Comment: That error mean that the `parts` objects is being defined after `MakeCluster` function. It should be before. Without the loop you are trying or modyfing any part of the answer code: Can you execute successfully the code in the answer? If not, the error message is the same (` "Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'parts' not found"`)?

Comment: @JeppeOlsen I edited my answer for Windows OS support. if you use Windows, try the code I have added.

Comment: This is one way to go, and definitely speeds things up. Thumps up.

Answer (score 3):

If you can live with some slight "inaccuracies" on the borders of the polygons, you can
achieve a very fast processing by rasterizing the shapefile, and then extracting the value
of the points on the raster using `raster::extract`.
Something like this would work, and outputs a SpatialPointsDataFrame.

```
library(rgdal)
library(gdalUtils)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(lazyeval)
library(tidyr)
download.file("http://gis.ices.dk/shapefiles/ICES_ecoregions.zip",
              destfile = "ICES_ecoregions.zip")
unzip("ICES_ecoregions.zip")

# read eco region shapefiles
ices_eco <- sf::read_sf("ICES_ecoregions_20150113_no_land.shp")
## Make a large data.frame (361,722 rows) with positions in the North Sea:
lon <- seq(-18.025, 32.025, by=0.05)
lat <- seq(48.025, 66.025, by=0.05)
c <- expand.grid(lon=lon, lat=lat)

# Get the Ecoregion for each position
pings  <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(c, 
                                 data = data.frame(id = 1:dim(c)[1]), 
                                 proj4string = CRS(st_crs(ices_eco)$proj4string))

extr_data = list()
temprast  <- tempfile(fileext = ".tif")
tempshape <- tempfile(fileext = ".shp")
counter = 1
for (poly_n in seq_along(along = ices_eco$Ecoregion))  {

  message("Working on polygon: ", poly_n)
  # extract one polygon andrasterize it with 0.1 deg resolution
  subshape    <- ices_eco[poly_n,]
  st_write(subshape, tempshape, update = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)

  # crop the points dataframe on the extent of the rasterized polygon
  # to save time
  subpoints   <- raster::crop(pings, extent(as.numeric(st_bbox(subshape))[c(1,3,2,4)]))

  # if there are points "left", extract the value of the rasterized polygon, for each point
  if (!is.null(subpoints)) {
    rast <- gdal_rasterize(tempshape, temprast, burn = poly_n,
                           tr = c(0.01,0.01), a_nodata = -999,
                           output_Raster = TRUE)
    extr_points <- raster::extract(rast, subpoints, sp = TRUE)

    extr_points <- extr_points[which(extr_points@data[ , 2] == poly_n), ] %>%
      as("sf")

    # If any of the points fell in the polygon, extract the value and return them in
    # the list. otherwise, return null

    if ((dim(extr_points)[1]) != 0 ) {
      extr_data[[counter]] <- extr_points
      counter <- counter + 1
    }
  }
  unlink(temprast)
  unlink(tempshape)
}

# Do some juggling to remove duplicates and go back to a SpatialPointsDataFrame
out <- data.table::rbindlist(extr_data) %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
  # Following two lines needed to remove few "duplicated" points. I think you get those
  # for points falling on the boundary between two cells. Increasing resolution in rasterization 
  # could avoid this
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize_(ecoregion = interp(~first(var), var = as.name(names(extr_data[[1]])[2])),
                    geometry  = interp(~vargeo[1],  vargeo = as.name("geometry"))) %>% 
  # transform bakck to a spatialpointsdataframe
  sf::st_as_sf() %>%
  as("Spatial") 

# Add the extracted info to the original SpatialPointsDataFrame
pings@data <- dplyr::left_join(pings@data, out@data) 
head(pings@data)
summary(pings)

>     head(pings@data)
  id ecoregion
1  1        17
2  2        17
3  3        17
4  4        17
5  5        17
6  6        17
>     summary(pings)
Object of class SpatialPointsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min    max
lon -18.025 32.025
lat  48.025 66.025
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string :
[+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0]
Number of points: 361722
Data attributes:
       id           ecoregion     
 Min.   :     1   Min.   : 9.00   
 1st Qu.: 90431   1st Qu.: 9.00   
 Median :180862   Median :11.00   
 Mean   :180862   Mean   :11.86   
 3rd Qu.:271292   3rd Qu.:15.00   
 Max.   :361722   Max.   :17.00   
                  NA's   :180720
```

On my PC, this completes in about 1 minute.
Note that in the code above, Im also processing one "polygon" at a time to further increase speed
and avoid creating a huge temporary raster file. Additionally, Im using the `sf` functions for
reading and writing shapefiles, which are much faster than the `rgdal` ones.

Also, I'm rasterizing the shapefile to a 0.01x0.01 degrees resolution'. You can reduce the
possibility of "errors" by increasing the resolution of the rasterization changing the `tr` parameter in
`rast <- gdal_rasterize(tempshape, temprast, burn = poly_n, tr = c(0.01,0.01), a_nodata = -999, output_Raster = TRUE)`

HTH !

Comment: I was thinking in the same lines, but the "inaccuracies" that you yourself points out makes this approach less appealing. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

### Fast without fancy programming: gContains from package rgeos

```
download.file("http://gis.ices.dk/shapefiles/ICES_ecoregions.zip",
              destfile = "ICES_ecoregions.zip")
unzip("ICES_ecoregions.zip")
```

Read eco region shapefiles

```
ices_eco <- rgdal::readOGR(".", "ICES_ecoregions_20171207_erase_ESRI", verbose=FALSE)
```

Make a large data.frame (361,722 rows) with positions in the North Sea:

```
lon <- seq(-18.025, 32.025, by=0.05)
lat <- seq(48.025, 66.025, by=0.05)
c <- expand.grid(lon=lon, lat=lat)
```

Get the Ecoregion for each position

```
pings  <- sp::SpatialPoints(c[c('lon','lat')], proj4string=ices_eco@proj4string)
res <- rgeos::gContains(ices_eco, pings, byid=T, prepared=T, returnDense=T)
c$area <- apply(res, 1, which)
```