# Set the minimum and maximum values for an elevation raster in R

Tags: raster, r, elevation, sp, rgdal

I have a raster that displays elevational values at a global scale. I would like to set the minimum and maximum values based on the values I would like to choose.

```
> elev
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 18000, 43200, 777600000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.008333334, 0.008333334  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -60, 90.00001  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
data source : E:\Data\Elevation_Data\alt\alt 
names       : alt 
values      : -431, 8233  (min, max)
attributes  :
     ID COUNT
 from: -431     2
 to  : 8233     1

> image(elev, zlim=c(0,1200))
```

The above command simply plots an image with the necessary values, but I would like a raster with just those limits.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the commented and reproducible example below. You can assign `NA` values to your elevation `RasterLayer` as `elev[elev < 0] <- NA` and `elev[elev > 1200] <- NA`.

```
# Load libraries
library('raster')
library('rgdal')
library('mapview') # interactive map viewing in R

# Get DEM data example
elev <- getData('alt', country = 'URY')
```

[image: rasterLayer]

```
# Plot elevation data example 
mapview(elev)

# Define and query thresholds 
min <- 50
max <- 300

elev2 <- elev
elev2[elev <= min] <- NA
elev2[elev >= max] <- NA

# Plot elevation with threshold max min
mapview(elev2)
```

[image: rasterlayer2]

```
print(elev2) # see min and max values

#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 612, 648, 396576  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : -58.5, -53.1, -35.1, -30  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#data source : in memory
#names       : URY_msk_alt 
#values      : 51, 299  (min, max)
```

**Note:** more help and so nice information about rasters in R here [Raster Data in R - The Basics](http://neondataskills.org/R/Raster-Data-In-R/)

Comment: Thanks @Guzman for a detailed answer. Looks like this works, but takes a ton of time for a large raster that spans the entire globe. I am going to crop it to my region of interest and try it again.

Comment: @VijayRamesh you are welcome! Maybe you can parallelize the function using the `parallel` package to speed up the process. You can check this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241255/efficient-spatial-joining-for-large-dataset-in-r/241338#241338 for help. It's not about querying rasters but you can get the logic behind parallel processing. And you will find more info there.

Comment: @Guzmán the link to Raster Data in R - The Basics is broken.

Comment: Also, thanks for the beautiful visualization using the mapview package. Seems like an excellent resource :)

Comment: @VijayRamesh I think `mapview` package is great! It really makes easy interact with spatial data in R.